# What qualities to look for in a NAS for home use

Tags: raid, nas

I am looking to buy a NAS to use to store all of my media and stream HD (1080p/blue ray) to 3 devices in parallel. Also to use it as a file storage device for Macs and PC's with Raid 10 or 5. I have looked at two different NAS solutions.

The difference between the two are:

- 1.2Ghz Marvell processor vs a 1.6Ghz Marvell
- 256 MB DDR2 RAM vs 512 DDR3 RAM
- SAMBA Benchmark: 412: read - 69.3 MB/s write - 32.7MB/s 419 P +: read -100.2MB/s write - 45.4MB/s

With this in mind, what speed do I need to rip a blu-ray disk smoothly?

I know that the network may be a bottle neck so what is the max speed over wireless N & G? Would it be better to use gigabit ethernet? Will I see less issues revolving around speed?

What benefits are gained from the better processor and RAM?

Comment: See: [Would more RAM or more CPU be better for a NAS (Network drive)?](http://superuser.com/questions/344414/would-more-ram-or-more-cpu-be-better-for-a-nas-network-drive)

Comment: Doesnt really address the points for my needs (parallel hd streaming and file sharing)

Answer (score 0):

A blue ray disk has the following bandwidth requirements:

- Audio+Video+Subtitles 48.0 Mbit/s
- Raw data transfer 53.95 Mbit/s

G is 54 Mbit/s

N routers/AP can be 150/300/450

but all streams will share the same bandwidth, thus - for 3 parallel streams you must have ~54*3 = 162 Mbit/s. N 300 will be (theoretically) OK, but I'll recommend to use device with [MIMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO) support